# Intent(context, Class) not working Gives error when I pass in the class object

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on android. I made a class and I'm creating a list programmatically. Everything is working fine except when I pass the class object into the Intent constructor, java gives me an error that it cannot resolve the variable.

```
public class HomePageActivity extends ListActivity {

String courses[]= {"MobileComputing", "Professional Issues",
        "Advance Programming", "Network Security", "Final Year Project-1"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomePageActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try {
        Class courseOne = Class.forName("com.fastnuces.keepmeposted.courseone");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent CourseOneScr = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, courseOne);
    startActivity(CourseOneScr);
    }
```

}

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Just did.

Comment: Can you also add the detailed error (stacktrace) ?

Comment: Is your error a compile time or runtime one? Is there a logcat or stacktrace you could supply if it's runtime?

Comment: probably becouse com.fastnuces.keepmeposted.courseone is the name of the package and not the class?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable outside of the `try/catch` or move your `Intent` inside.

```
 try {
    Class courseOne = Class.forName("com.fastnuces.keepmeposted.courseone");
    Intent CourseOneScr = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, courseOne);
    startActivity(CourseOneScr);  
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If it is inside the `try` then it would be unreachable if there was an `exception` and anything outside of it possibly wouldn't know about it.

Comment: @LucianNovac how would it not? The current issue the OP is having, "it cannot resolve the variable." is a scope problem.

Comment: He need that intent to work and if you put it into a try catch exception the intent will not work if that class does not exists

Comment: @LucianNovac yes, but he will only get an exception if the class *doesn't* exist. Therefore, if the class exists there will be no exception and the `Intent` will run fine. Otherwise, there is no class for the `Intent` to start.

Comment: the title of the question "Intent(context, Class) not working" if you put into a try catch will work?! I don't think so....

Comment: @LucianNovac yes, but see what the error is that the OP is having. That is the reason it isn't working. It is a compile error because the method can't recognize that variable!

Comment: I don't what to make a long chat with you here just read the title...in my opinion is a missunderstanding about what is the question about

Comment: @LucianNovac I don't either but look at the error the OP is getting, "it cannot resolve the variable." This is a *compile* error, not *runtime* as you are saying. And look at it, that variable is **clearly** out of scope. You can't do it that way with a 'try/catch`

Comment: Ok you are right related to the "it cannot resolve the variable" but does not resolve the "Intent(context, Class) not working"

Comment: It does resolve it if the full class name of the `Activity` he wants to launch is correct

Comment: @LucianNovac We don't know that there is a problem with the `Intent` constructor once it runs because it **can't** run! You are assuming there is a problem with something that we have no information on. What makes you think the constructor has a problem other than the variable isn't recognized?

Comment: dude just test it yourself into an example project and put a real class name and a fake that does not exist... you will see that...

Comment: I will see that the project doesn't compile if the variable he is trying to pass to the `Intent` is not in scope, it won't even run. If you change the `String` to an incorrect full class name, it will compile and throw an `Exception`.

Comment: @LucianNovac dude, I will see what? You are describing a problem that doesn't exist here. The current problem is simply the scope of the variable being passed to the `Intent` constructor. Once the OP fixes that he can *then* run it. Sure there could be other problems but none that are obvious. How do you know that isn't a class name?

Comment: Worked! I'm sorry for asking such stupid questions. I was following a tutorial and he did it this way. It was obviously out of scope. Thank you again!

Comment: @SaadRehman no problem. We all start somewhere. I do suggest you go through the Java docs if you are unfamiliar with Java before going much further with Android.

Comment: @LucianNovac do you see my point now? And we can delete all of the useless comments to get rid of the clutter if you want to undo the downvote, if you wish.